# Gap when drawing polygon on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm using the following to draw polygons on an html canvas:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var numberOfSides = 6,
    size = 20,
    Xcenter = 25,
    Ycenter = 25;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo (Xcenter +  size * Math.cos(0), Ycenter +  size *  Math.sin(0));          

for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfSides;i += 1) {
    ctx.lineTo (Xcenter + size * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides), Ycenter + size * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides));
}

ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.stroke();
```

Unfortunately, it leaves a gap at the end of the polygon. Any idea how to fix this?

[Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/757mavjb/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of drawing to all 6 points, only draw to the first 5 and then call `ctx.closePath();`

http://jsfiddle.net/757mavjb/2/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var numberOfSides = 6,
    size = 20,
    Xcenter = 25,
    Ycenter = 25;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo (Xcenter +  size * Math.cos(0), Ycenter +  size *  Math.sin(0));          

for (var i = 1; i < numberOfSides;i += 1) {
    ctx.lineTo (Xcenter + size * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides), Ycenter + size * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides));
}
ctx.closePath();

ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.stroke();
```

(Note the change from `i <= numberOfSides` to `i < numberOfSides`)

Answer (score 2):

Try drawing one more side in order to fill the gap:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfSides+1;i += 1) {
    ctx.lineTo (Xcenter + size * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides), Ycenter + size * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides));
}
```